# Angular 6 save API call into variable of service

Tags: angular, rest, publish-subscribe

I would like to call an API only the first time and then return the variable saved into service. 
I changed my code so:

```
export class CategoryService {
  categories: Category[]
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private handleError: HandleErrorService) {
  }

  /************ REST CALLS *****************/
  /**
   * Retrieve configuration categories 
   */
  private getListCategories() {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>("/api/configuration/category").pipe(
      map(res => {
        this.categories = res;
        return res;
      }),
      catchError(err => this.handleError.handleError(err, { severity: 'error', summary: 'Error retrieving the list of categories', life: 5000 })) // then handle the error;
    );
  }
  /************ CATEGORY MANAGEMENT ************/
  get getCategories() {
    if (this.categories)
      return this.categories;
    else
      this.getListCategories().subscribe((categories:Category[])=>{
        return categories;
      });
  }

}
```

but in my `getCategories` I have to wait the response of API call. There is a pattern or best practice to achieve my target? Sure I can set the service variable from component but after that other component may call the API instead of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from a subscription. It is asynchronous. You have several options, such as transform the Observable to a Promise and works with async/await, or you can return an observable and let who calls the service to subscribe to it.

Example:

```
get getCategories() {
    if (this.categories)
      return of(this.categories);
    else
      return this.getListCategories();
  }
```

And then you call the getCategories() method within a component

```
this.categoryService.getCategories.subscribe( categories => {
   //console.log(categories)
})
```

Take a look at this [blog post](https://medium.com/@garfunkel61/https-medium-com-garfunkel61-angular-data-provider-services-in-memory-data-cache-c495a0ac35da), the author explains how to build a cache mechanism in an Angular's service.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use an Observable for this to keep the subscribe function outside of the service for this type of thing.

```
getCategories() {
  return this.categories
    ? of(this.categories)
    : this.getListCategories().do((categories:Category[]) => {
        this.categories = categories;
      });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use function localStorage to save your value and after recover it until you don't close your browser window.

```js
localStorage.setItem("key","value")
//after you can get the value using 
localStorage.getItem("key")
```

Don't forget that getItem will always return a String and setItem need a String as value and key

Comment: This is not a good approach. First, the usage of localStorage this way is not the best way, it should be used a service that abstracts and injects the LocalStorage. The other problem is that when you set the value in the localStorage, you won't know that it has been set outside the asynchronous block code.